# How do I edit more than one one-to-many entities in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets imagine I want to create a task app.

In this app I have users, e.g.

```
id      name   
1       phil
2       anette
```

Every user can have x amount of task lists, e.g.

```
id     user_id    name
1      1          test
2      1          another test
3      2          cheers
```

Again, every task list can have a list of tasks, e.g.:

```
id     tasklist_id    name
1      1              very important task
2      2              important task
3      1              another task in first list
4      3              item for anette
```

The entity mapping with **Doctrine** worked out fine. Also the integration of **FOSUserBundle**. I actually can login as an user and can see my very own task lists.

But what it not possible for me to create is a way so that a user can edit the tasks in a task list. Also it should be noted that only the user which owns a specific task list should be able to edit it and its childs. Via my approach (auto generated crud templates) you can take any id and change every content.

What I thought about to this point:

- If I supply the task list id to the controller (to show all tasks of a specific list), the id is lost after an update and all tasks from all users will be shown. (I created the forms and the controller via the crud generator `php app/console generate:doctrine:crud`)
- I thought about putting the task list id into the session, but find this is a bad solution
- I tried searching for different approaches (e.g. `symfony2 pass parameter to subentity` or `symfony2 pass controller variable`) but could not find any information to this topic other than changing the controller into a service
- I should create a service, maybe out of the task list controller or the task controller. But I am not sure about this approach.

Which are correct ways regarding symfony2 to solve this (almost certainly common) problem? How can I supply a user with a way to edit his tasks lists, but also to edit specific tasks? Or to be more generic, how to edit more than one one-to-many relationships in symfony?

Comment: Your first thought is correct, you need to create an action in the controller which allows editing of a specific list `listEditAction($id)` and after a succesfull submit and persist of the data on a subtask you need to redirect to this action with the same parameter, surely you have all this logic in your controllers already don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Concerning your security problem, this is a different matter, but you should check in your controller (in EditAction) that the list you're trying to edit belongs to the logged in user.